# Why am I getting an insert blob error when using MySql v8.0 instead of v5.1?

Tags: mysql, insert, blob

I created the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `player__main` (
  `row` varbinary(256) NOT NULL,
  `schema_id` int NOT NULL,
  `version` int NOT NULL,
  `format` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `avro` mediumblob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`row`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Then, I run my script below on MySql v5.17:

```sql
insert into player__main (row, schema_id, version, format, avro) VALUES (x'61646D696E',11,1,0,x'0A61646D69');

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)
```

However, when I execute the code below in MySql v8.0:

```sql
insert into player__main (row, schema_id, version, format, avro) VALUES (x'61646D696E',11,1,0,x'0A61646D69');
```

I get this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'row, schema_id, version, format, avro) VALUES
> (x'61646D696E',11,1,0,x'0A61646D69' at line 1

It's the same query but it returns different results depending of the version of MySql I am using.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is there a server setting for this behaviour? The [documentation shows the same format for 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/hexadecimal-literals.html). It could be you need the `X'...'` notation for strings, vs. `0x...` for numbers.

Comment: I only disable ssl: ?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false

Answer (score 0):

I think the real problem here is `row` is a [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-R) in 8:

> `ROW` `(R);` became reserved in 8.0.2

You'll need to rename that column, or escape it going forward:

```sql
INSERT INTO player_main (`row`, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is OK:  insert into player__main (\`row\`, schema_id, version, format, avro) VALUES (0x61646D696E,11,1,0,0x0A61646D69);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

Comment: But why select binary (0x61646D696E) show difference results?

Comment: My theory is MySQL 8 interprets that as a numerical value instead of a string.